# Getting an error while reading image using cv2.imread()

Tags: python, opencv

The train_data file looks like this: [image: Data set with image path]

The error while reading the image using imread function is as shown[image: Error message]

SystemError:  *returned NULL without setting an error*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Yes, I think I should have gone through them in detail. I'll make sure to keep things in mind, Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send the whole Pandas dataframe into `cv2.imread`.  You want to access the actual file itself.  You also want to append with the image, not a list containing just the image to allow for easier accessing:

```py
data = []
for i in range(len(train_data)):
    img_array = cv2.imread(train_data.loc[i, 'file'], 1)
    data.append(img_array)
```